# Проблема с подключением шрифта Open Sans Extra-Bold

Tags: шрифты

Скачиваю шрифт с гугл фонтс http://www.google.com/webfonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans
(Выбираю символы Cyrillic Extended (cyrillic-ext) и Latin (latin))

Обрабатываю шрифт шрифтобелкой, подключаю к странице

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'open_sansextrabold';
src: url('../fonts/opensans-extrabold-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/opensans-extrabold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/opensans-extrabold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/opensans-extrabold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/opensans-extrabold-webfont.svg#open_sansextrabold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

использую для элементов страницы, 
но начертание меняют только цифры и латинские буквы, на русские буквы подключенный шрифт не действует.

При этом если открыть шрифт в редакторе шрифтов и в Mapping переключиться на кириллицу,
вроде там все символы с правильными юникодами есть
[image]
Как подключить этот шрифт, чтобы русские символы тоже отображались как надо?

Answer (score 1):

Как подсказали на другом ресурсе, при обработке шрифтобелкой в настройках надо явно указать поддержку русского, иначе она удалит из шрифта все символы, кроме латиницы/цифр. Нужно поставить режим Expert, выбрать Custom subsetting, поставить галку Cyrillic. Или в данном случае можно вообще No subsetting, раз и так в шрифте только то, что нужно.